# autocomplete instant results in select options

Tags: 7, ajax

I am trying to have my select options filled with autocomplete results.
I have two fields, a textfield and a select(box). Autocomplete is working on my textfield. The thing that I am trying to get done is to have the results from autocomplete populate the options of my select(box)

How can this be done? Below a snippet of my autocomplete function:

```
function _cities_autocomplete($string) {

    $matches = array();
    $result = db_select('tabel', 'c')
        ->fields('c', array('product', 'w'))
        ->condition('product', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
        ->range(0, 10)
        ->execute();

    // save the query to matches
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $matches[$row->product] = check_plain($row->product) . ' w:' . ($row->w);
        }
    // Return the result to the form in json

  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

I tried using the code below instead of drupal_json_output() .. this is throwing an error.

```
return array(
   '#id' => 'overzicht_producten',
   '#type' => 'select',
   '#maxlength' => 60,
   '#value' => 'some value',
    '#options' => array( 0 => 'test1',  1 => 'test2',  2 => 'test3'),
 );
```

I accomplished to have dependent dropdown from the ajax example working. But the dependent select(box) is only populated after the textfield is losing focus, this is not desirable. I need to have my select(box) options populated exactly as autocomplete is populating the options below the textfield.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Would it work to just populate your form's <select> #options with your $matches instead of using autocomplete?